# Issue using CodeDOM

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, code-generation, codedom

I'm using this to compile with CodeDOM:

```
Dim provider As CodeDomProvider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("VisualBasic")

Dim parameters As New System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters()
' Add reference
parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll")
parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Windows.Forms.dll")
parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll")
parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Drawing.dll")
'Compile parameters
Dim Output1 As String = "OutputApp"
parameters.GenerateExecutable = True
parameters.OutputAssembly = Output1
parameters.CompilerOptions = "/target:winexe"

Dim strCode As String = sb.ToString
Dim CompileResults As New System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerResults(Nothing)

CompileResults = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, strCode)
```

The problem is i need to use lambda expressions and Split Overload method but codedom doesn't seem to recognize it, like this:

```
Dim t As New Threading.Thread(Sub() SharedMethods.DoStuff(True))
t.Start()
```

and this:

```
Dim strseveralcmds() As String = SharedMethods.DoRequests("mylink.txt").Replace(" ", String.Empty).Split({Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

Both lines when compiling with codeDOM throw "Expression was expected"...
For the first one i can manage myself for this project as i don't really need the parameter and can just use AddressOf, but i'd like to anyways...

Now for the second one i don't know any workaround as it must be newline string, not char...

Any suggestions? Why doesn't CodeDOM compile all .net code? Or am i missing something?

Comment: Why the answer was deleted? Seem'ed accurate... ?!

Comment: In order to run Lambda expressions, you will need to include a reference to LINQ.

Comment: I've searched for it but apparently it's only for .net 3.5+... any workaround for 2.0 ?

Comment: No, but CodeDOM is available for later versions of .NET. [Using the CodeDOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2k85ax6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: But i need to use .net 2.0... i'll try to get a workaround for my code then...
Thanks.